# How to search a string from end to beginning by RegEx

Tags: regex, perl

How to search a string from end to beginning by regular expression, for example:

- string: `a1a2a3xx`
- pattern: `((?:a\d){0,2}.*?)$`

I hope `$1` get `a2a3xx`, but by my practice, `$1` gets `a1a2a3xx`.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and tell us what currently goes wrong with your code? Your expression matches the string given, so I'm unclear about what the question is.

Comment: string: a1a2a3xx pattern: ((?:a\d){0,2}.*?)$   I hope $1 get a2a3xx, but by my practice, $1 get a1a2a3xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to get your desired results.

`((?:a\d){0,2}(?:(?!a\d).)*)$`

This expression will match after `a\d{0,2}` anything that does not match `a\d`